# Changing sort options in icon view

Tags: macos, finder

Is there any way to sort files in any way other than NAME while in ICON view? This is typically when in a file dialog (i.e. browser upload window) there are no options for sorting by Last Modified or similar, you have to be in DETAIL view for that.

Please see this screen shot as an example: http://cl.ly/0w0f3L0z3z0Q2n2E042F

Comment: from what I have been able to search, it appears it can't be done. I have tried with firefox and mail.app and I couldn't see any option to this effect. [removing my answer]

Comment: Good question! I concur with @bronzebeard I believe this can’t be done (add another bullet to the list of Finder Annoyances, jump to page 52…) ;)

Answer (score 1):

No.

I would suggest heading to http://bugreport.apple.com and filing a bug there. Apple does base, in part, what they do on the number of similar bug reports they get. If enough people want this same enhancement and file bug reports, there is a good chance Apple will get it done.

Answer (score 0):

File dialogs have had a pop-up menu for changing the arrange by mode since Lion:

[image]

There's still no way to change the sort by mode in icon view or column view. And the shortcuts for changing the sorting modes don't do anything.